# Handling action correctly using Redux-saga

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I'm new to Reactjs, so if anything wrong, just let me know.
I have one thing to ask about asynchronous, redux-saga.
Basically, I have one simple action: when I selected an item => delete it, if it's success, call api that get all items, again
Like this: ( this is happened inside my saga)

```
export function* delete (action)
   yield call(service.deleteanitem)
   ....
   yield call(service.getall)
   yield put {type: 'getall'}
```

My idea is, I want it's sequential, I mean, when I delete item, a 'getall' action have to 'wait' whenever the previous action done, then its turn.
Any suggestion ?

Comment: Sorry, could clarify how is the flow of your saga? action delete => service delete => service get all => action get all=> ??? anything else? It it should stop here?

Comment: @Ematipico yeah, it is. My problem is, the action getall should wait before service/ action delete done.

Comment: When you're using yield like that, the subsequent calls are waiting for the yield to return something. So as your code is laid out, it is already being ran in sequence.

Answer (score 0):

> a 'getall' action have to 'wait' whenever the previous action done,
>   then its turn.

Just use full-weight `fork` saga process and build your own custom execution flow with asynchronous operations.

Example which covers any case with cross await dependencies:

```
function* sagaProc() {
  let controlPromise, controlResolve;
  while(true) {
    // ...
    controlPromise = new Promise(resolve => (controlResolve = resolve))
    socket.on('message', msg => controlResolve(msg))
    yield put({ type: 'SOME_REQUEST' })
    yield call(() => fetch('SOME_URL'))
    const message = yield call(() => controlPromise)
    yield put({ type: 'SOME_RESPONSE', ...message })
    // ...
  }
}

function* mainSaga() {
  // ...
  yield fork(sagaProc)
  // ...
}
```